# TFS and keyword expansion

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe, keyword-expansion

We've just moved some projects from Microsoft Visual SourceSafe (VSS) to Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) and have now noticed that keyword expansion no longer works.

For instance, keywords like `$Log$` or `$Header$` are no longer expanded to the correct values.

Can anyone tell us why this is?

Answer (score 2):

TFS does not support keyword expansion. See the following post for more information:

- [Keyword expansion in TFS](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2007/07/07/keyword-expansion-in-tfs.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is now a free tool available: http://logsubstpol.codeplex.com/

I don't know how well it works.  Presumably they read Buck's caveats!

Comment: It works very well. I've used it for several years. Unfortunately it isn't available for VS2015+ or AzureDevOps.